# Go Golang : Merge Sort Stack Overflow

Tags: merge, go, stack-overflow, mergesort

http://play.golang.org/p/rRccL6YHtQ

I just implement the same code as in CLRS

```
Pseudocode from CLRS

Merge-Sort(A, p, r)
    if p < r
        q = [(q+r)/2]
        Merge-Sort(A, p, q)
        Merge-Sort(A, q+1, r)
        Merge(A, p, q, r)

Merge(A, p, q, r)
    n_1 = q - p + 1
    n_2 = r - q
    let L[1 .. n_1 + 1]  and R[1 .. n_2 + 1] be new arrays

    for i = 1 to n_1
            L[i] = A[p+i-1]

    for j = 1 to n_2
            R[j] = A[q+j]

    L[n_1 + 1] = INFINITE
    R[n_2 + 1] = INFINITE
    i = 1
    j = 1

    for k = p to r
        if L[i] <= R[j]
                A[k] = L[i]
                i = i + 1
        else A[k] = R[j]
                j = j + 1
```

But I am getting the stack overflow in the merge sort.

```
        [9 -13 4 -2 3 1 -10 21 12]
        runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 250000000-byte limit
        fatal error: stack overflow

        runtime stack:
        runtime.throw(0x1b4980, 0x20280)
```

How do I make this work?

```
        func MergeSort(slice []int, first, last int) {

            if len(slice) < 2 {
                return
            }

            if first < last {
                mid := len(slice) / 2
                MergeSort(slice, first, mid)
                MergeSort(slice, mid+1, last)
                Merge(slice, first, mid, last)
            }
        }
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: I have no useful comment other than to say it's nice to see a question on stack overflow that is literally about a stack overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mid := len(slice) / 2
```

That's not where the middle should go. The middle is  supposed to be halfway between `first` and `last`, which define the region of the slice you're sorting, not halfway through the slice. Alternatively, you can slice the slice to make new slices and drop `first` and `last`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be re-slicing the slice you're merge-sorting, so there is no termination of the recursion.

You could either re-slice the slice before recursion, or you can do something like `length := last - first` (this may have an off-by-one, depending if "last" is the last index or one past the last index) and then go from there.